# Homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^1$, but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^1$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

What is an intuitive example of a topological object which is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^1$, but **not** homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: Would you be happy with $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb S^1$? Any contractible space (not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$) in place of $\mathbb R^n$ would work.

Comment: wouldn't $\mathbb{S}^1$ itself work?

Comment: The Möbius strip is a popular shape that is also homotopy equivalent to the circle.

Comment: The current phrasing of the question allows some trivial answers, so I guess it should be interpreted as a question about existence of spaces that are homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ but not homeomorphic to $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$

Answer (score 2):

The shape of the letter Q (a circle with a segment attached). You can retract the segment to its root point on the circle.

Comment: Great example! One can think about the characters 6, 9, b, p, R, A, Ð, þ and ¤ as well